# Formal definition of antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm learning real analysis and I have known the rigorous definition of derivative of a function of 1 variable at 1 point:

> [image]

and its general version when considering a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$:

> [image]

I have 2 questions concerning the antiderivative please:

1. In the case of single variable function, does there exist a rigorous definition of antiderivative ? Could you please tell me that definition ?
2. Does the notion of antiderivative still exist when we talk about a function of multivariable ? Is there any rigorous definition of antiderivative in such a case ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes and yes. You'll learn them when you learn integration. Let's just say that the picture is slightly more complicated with integration.

Comment: @DonThousand: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I have recently learned some chapters of measure theory (up to the construction of Lebesgue integral). However, i have not seen the author defines the concept of antiderivative anywhere. Could you kindly suggest me a source that I could read about the antiderivative in the general case? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, assuming that the function is sufficiently well-behaved, the indefinite integral is the set of antiderivatives. Stoke's theorem can be viewed as a statement of this fact (although I don't particularly like this viewpoint)

Comment: @DonThousand : Hi, but unfortunately, I don't think there exists the rigorous concept of indefinite integral. I'm quite confused as I have never come across the definition of indefinite integral in the real analysis course

Comment: Well, there is, it's just that it isn't often called that. An indefinite integral is simply one that is defined for any boundary conditions. That's what I mean when I say that Stoke's theorem can be viewed as a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus in the sense that it establishes the integral as the set of antiderivatives in a rather general setting.

Comment: @DonThousand Could you please tell me what do you mean by "defined for any boundary condition" ?

Comment: An indefinite integral, to put it lightly, is a function that takes as input the boundary on which to evaluate the integral, and then evaluates the definite integral on that boundary. Thus, it is defined for any boundary condition,.

Comment: @DonThousand it seems to me that the concept of antiderivative only exists in 1 dimension (according to the answer of chappers in this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210649/is-there-a-notion-of-indefinite-lebesgue-integral)

Comment: It's a bit of a matter of opinion, I guess. I see differential forms (via Stokes) as an extension of indefinite integrals. To be precise, given forms $\omega,\gamma$ such that $d\gamma=\omega$, $$\int_{d\Omega}\gamma=\int_{\Omega}\omega$$for all measurable sets $\Omega$. In this sense, I'd view $\gamma$ as the antiderivative of $\omega$

Comment: Please do not use pictures to convey information. [See here for the reason why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the antiderivative is simple:

> A function $f$ defined on a set $X$ has an *antiderivative* $g$ if $g$ is defined and differentiable on all points of $X$, and $g' = f$.

Note that the set $X$ cannot have any isolated points, as $g$ must be differentiable at every point, and differentiability is not defined at isolated points.

The same definition works for both the simple derivative, in which case $X \subseteq \Bbb R; f, g : X \to \Bbb R$, or the multivariate version, in which case $X \subset \Bbb R^m; g : X \to \Bbb R^n$ and $f : X \to L(\Bbb R^m, \Bbb R^n)$, the space of all linear operators from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$.

This definition does not require integration. It is simply the inverse of differentiation. It has the weakness that there is not just one antiderivative, but rather when an antiderivative exists at all, adding a constant gives another antiderivative. The fact that all antiderivatives of the same function must differ from each other by constants has to be proven. But this can be accomplished by the mean value theorem.

However, it is by integration theory that we prove continuous functions always have antiderivatives.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It helps a lot. I would like to ask if the concept of integration in the general setting (for example Lebesgue integration) has anything to do with antiderivative or not ? In single variable calculus, There is the FTC that links the 2 concepts. However, as long as I study Lesbesgue integral, i have never seen the antiderivative anymore. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lebesgue integration is a generalization of Riemann integration. Any Riemann-integrable function is also Lebesgue-integrable, and the two integrals have the same value. Thus the FTC automatically holds for Lebegue integration as well. You don't hear about antiderivatives anymore because they have now become background knowledge you are just expected to know. The Lebesgue integral has a rich theory with many interesting avenues to explore. But you won't be able to explore them if the book spends its time rehashing what you already know.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! However, as far as I know, there are functions  which are Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable. And to calculate the Lebesgue integration of such functions, I often see they apply directly the definition of Lebesgue integration instead of trying to find the antiderivatives (and apply FTC). Could you kindly explain why do they choose a more difficult way ? (for me, subtracting 2 antiderivaties is much more convenient than using the definition). Thank you very much!!

Comment: I said Lebesgue generalizes Riemann. That means it covers everything Riemann does, and *more*. So yes, there are functions that are Lebesgue integrable that are not Riemann integrable. But whenever a function is Riemann integrable, it is also Lebesgue integrable, and the two integrals agree in their value.  They do it the difficult way because they are demonstrating how the Lebesgue integral works, and like always, demonstrations are done with simple problems that are easier to calculate. But what makes the problem simple also makes it Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightment. So basically, if there is a function $f$ which is Lebesgue integrable and not Riemann integrable, if we could find its antiderivative, we could also apply the FTC (i.e. evaluate the antiderivative at boundaries) to calculate its Lebesgue integration, right ? Thank you very much, this is my last question concerning this topic.

Comment: The FTC requires the integrand to be continuous. Continuous functions are Riemann Integrable. So no, you cannot use it to find the Lebesgue integral of a non-Riemann-Integrable function.

Comment: Hi, i would like to come back to this question.  Could you please tell me whether there exists a version of FTC that connect the derivatives (in your definition, in high dimension) and the integral or not ? It seems to me that in the general setting, integral and derivative are 2 very different things, not like in the case of single variable calculus. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In higher dimensions, there are several theorems corresponding to the FTC, depending on the space and the derivative used. These include Green's Theorem, Stokes' Theorem, and Gauss' Theorem. All of them and the FTC are special cases of the "generalized Stokes' Theorem" of differential geometry, which states that if $M$ is a manifold with boundary $\partial M$ and $\omega$ is a form on $M$, then $$\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega$$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In the generalized Stokes's theorem, could you please tell me which integral is used ? Is it Lebesgue integral or Riemann integral ? I am quite confused! Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: Either one. The conditions on $\omega$ are sufficient one could even resort to the Cauchy Integral that predated Riemann's (effectively Riemann's integral, but with all partitions of fixed interval width - the same theorems apply, but you have to assume continuity of the integrand to prove anything).